# how to pass multiple variable to html template Using PhpMailer?

Tags: php, html, email, phpmailer

I want to pass multiple variable to Mail template page and echo to that page using phpmailer library.

I have two variables to pass welcome.php page and echo there.

```
$name = 'example';
$email = 'example@mail.com';
```

I have use this code

```
 $mail->MsgHTML(str_replace('[emailhere]', $email, file_get_contents('welcome.php')), dirname(__FILE__));
```

Comment: Uh, what? Could you clarify your question a bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send arrays to [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to replace multiple values.

For example:

```
$message = str_replace(
    array(
      '[emailhere]',
      '[namehere]'
    ),
    array(
       $email,
       $name
    ),
    file_get_contents('welcome.php')
);
```

By the way, you should probably not give your template a `php` extension as it will parse any php if you call or include it directly. So that could be a security risk if users can modify templates.

Comment: Time for (another) coffee then ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- This is weird ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You may use output buffering.

Echo variables on your template file ($template):
for ex:

```
<p><?=$name?></p>
```

Then include it and pass through output buffering

```
ob_start(); //Start output buffering
include('welcome.php'); //include your template file
$template = ob_get_clean(); //Get current buffer contents and delete current output buffer
$mail->msgHTML($template); // Add html content into your PHP MAILER class
```